# Automated test tasks using TFS / Scrum

Tags: tfs, scrum

My group supports automated testing for our org.  We have defined a process by which scrum based product teams request us to run automation against builds that are candidates for production.  There is some debate about whether this "effort" should be documented as a TFS task under a larger, preexisting "prepare this release for production" PBI, or whether this "effort" should be added to the backlog as its own PBI.

What is good practice in your experience?

Answer (score 1):

Scrum teams should not have dependencies on other teams to release their changes.

So a good practise would be to let the Scrum to run the automation, maybe even integrate someone from your group into their team to make it truly cross functional.

> Scrum is about enabling teams to self-organize towards a process that
>   maximizes their ability to frequently deliver working software and
>   adjust their process based on the feedback it generates from
>   stakeholders, customers and users. And anything that stands in the way
>   of self-organization should be removed or reduced.
>
> read more [here...](http://blog.agilistic.nl/what-it-means-to-be-a-cross-functional-team-and-what-it-doesnt/)

Now the team could create a PBI todo a release or just release after each user story is completed as my teams are doing.

Maybe it is harsh to hear, but silos should not exist in an Agile organisation, try and start eliminating them now! :)

Another way of doing this is to automate the whole process of running automated tests. Read the book about [continuous delivery](https://www.thoughtworks.com/continuous-delivery).

Comment: We run automation for our entire solution set, which is comprised of a number of different products, each with their separate automation.  Our automation is on behalf of the solution's release manager, and covers the entire system.  Your suggestion is good, but I'm not sure our org is mature enough in scrum to line up that way (and won't be for some time).

Comment: As you have two choices be Agile experiment with one for two weeks, then experiment with the other one for two weeks and pick the one that feels right. Don't talk to much to find the perfect solution, just start using one and evaluate. Just make sure nothing is set to stone, because that limits you in the future. Make any process flexible and adaptable. Goodluck :)